# Blender keeps crashing

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

My scene keeps crashing. It crashes every time it reaches frame 4. I think it’s a complex scene, but I don’t know where I can see the informations about the scene that will tell me what the problem is, since it keeps crashing at frame 4? I am rendering in cycles and I have both been trying to use CPU and GPU Compute. None of them makes a diffrence. I’m using an iMac with 64 GB ram and Radeon Pro 580 8 GB Graphiccard? Can you tell what the problem might be?

---

[image]
[image]

Still don't know what these information means? :) Is it too much for what my computer can do?

Comment: If you right click on the grey bar at the bottom of your blender workspace you can choose what scene information you'd like to display. Turn them all on, take a screen shot and add to your post. It's always helpful to share as much information about your project as possible. Either as screenshots or the blend file itself. It becomes much easier to troubleshoot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbzs1.png

Comment: Hello and welcome! This looks very much like a bug to me. Probably related to the hardware or the graphics card drivers. ...But maybe there is still an expert in this field who can answer the question before I close this, because the question is either related to a bug or strictly speaking not related to the use of Blender.

Comment: You have around 3.7 million polygons in your scene(seen next to the faces section on your status bar). Blender should comfortably handle that amount with a machine like yours.
As quellenform mentioned, it's likely a bug but it would be helpful if you shared more about the scene including screenshots, before ruling anything out.

Comment: I think I have attached a photo of my scene now in my post :)

Comment: You should probably find out where the problem is. You can do this by testing. I would first start turning rendering features off like denoise, you could also delete objects in your scene one by one to see when the problem disapears if it is caused by some object. If it is an object, and you find out which one, you can inspect what's wrong with it, maybe it's something in the shader or something like that. The ide is to reduce the scene bit by bit until it starts working so you know where the problem is. Check compositing, scene and world settings and basically everything you can think of.

Comment: I'll try that! thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: I can also see you have a few modifiers across the project. Depending on their setup these can contribute to long render times or crashes. As Martynas suggests go through your project and rule out issues individually. Switch off any non essential modifiers and activate them individually to see if the issue lies there. If the modifiers are all related to the flip simulation then test different resolution values.